# Timeout on ToList() in Entity Framework when using a `Contains` predicate

Tags: c#, entity-framework, full-text-search

I have this simple query in EF :

```
            int chunkSize = 5;

            var chunkQueryBase = _sdb.Entities.Where(m => 
            m.Title.Contains("Appreciate")
            || m.Title.Contains("appreciate")
            || m.Title.Contains("APPRECIATE")
            ).OrderBy(c => c.Id);

            var chunkQuery = chunkQueryBase.Take(chunkSize);

            var chunks = chunkQuery.ToList();
```

I'm getting timeout error on the last line. As you can see, only 5 records are taken. Why am I getting this error? Thanks.

Comment: Because you asked to perform a `LIKE '%appreciate%'` search on the entire table which can't use indexes, then aksed for all the results to be sorted. The multiple `Contains` calls aren't necessary - SQL comparisons are typically case insensitive, unless you created the table with a case sensitive collation. How many rows are there, and why are you using a `LIKE '%appreciate%'` clause in the first place?

Comment: If you really want to perform a full-text search, create an FTS index on the table and use [a full text search query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142583.aspx).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `appreciate` is an example. Actually I'm searching for 25 words. and the table has about 1100000 rows. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is clear then. You perform a full table scan on 1M rows, and then you request an ordering of the results. That's definitely going to take more than whatever the execution timeout is. The real fix is to stop doing that and either change the database schema to support your queries (why search for "appreciate" in the title?) or add a full text index and use `CONTAINS` or `CONTAINSTABLE`. The hack is to increase the execution timeout. Have you tried running the same SQL query in SSMS? How long does it take?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for your comment. It takes 4 minutes in SSMS.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Can you tell me how to increase timeout?  Thanks.